# php echo in another div

Tags: php, text

How to show some text in another place if is some condition is satisfied ??

I need this for comment box with recaptcha.

My example:

```
if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])){
              $captcha=$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
            }
            if(!$captcha){
              echo '<h2>**Text who i want show in another place in html.**</h2>';
              exit;
            }
            $response=file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=my secret key response=".$captcha."&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
            if($response.success==false)
            {
              echo '<h2>You are spammer ! Get the @$%K out</h2>';
            }else
            {
              echo '<h2>Thanks for posting comment.</h2>';
            }
    $insert=mysql_query("INSERT INTO comment (name,comment) VALUES ('$name','$comment') ");
    echo "<meta HTTP-EQUIV='REFRESH' content='0; url=commentindex.php'>";
    }
    else
    {
    echo "please fill out all fields";
    }
    }
```

Comment: your code has lot of errors. can you edit your question and post a working code ?

Answer (score 0):

Assign to session

```
session_start();

$_SESSION['texthere'] = "your text here";
```

Then you can print session anywhere you want as long as you start

Answer (score 0):

your current code `echo` something then exits right after.

If you want to let the script continue and display text later on the page, you can store the text in a variable named `$message_result` for example, then do `<?php echo $message_result ?>` where you want to display it in the html.

you may probably have to add some if/else to avoid some instruction you wrote (like the mysql insertion)